Have I corrupted my system header file(endian.h)?
I was trying to fuzz a program using libprotobuf mutator and libfuzzer. I had 2 errors indicating that the protobuf header files were not installed when I compiled. So while trying to resolve the errors, I run the command:
sudo cp -r src/google/protobuf/*.h /usr/local/include/
I believe this was a mistake but I am not sure. But then when I compile again I got 11 errors. The whole list of errors are:
In file included from calc.cc:3:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/c++/11/cmath:47:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/c++/11/bits/std_abs.h:38:
In file included from /usr/include/stdlib.h:395:
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:176:
/usr/local/include/endian.h:75:17: error: functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded
   75 | inline uint32_t FromHost(uint32_t value) {
      |        ~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/include/endian.h:67:17: note: previous definition is here
   67 | inline uint16_t FromHost(uint16_t value) {
      |        ~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/include/endian.h:83:17: error: functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded
   83 | inline uint64_t FromHost(uint64_t value) {
      |        ~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/include/endian.h:67:17: note: previous definition is here
   67 | inline uint16_t FromHost(uint16_t value) {
      |        ~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/include/endian.h:99:17: error: functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded
   99 | inline uint32_t ToHost(uint32_t value) {
      |        ~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/include/endian.h:91:17: note: previous definition is here
   91 | inline uint16_t ToHost(uint16_t value) {
      |        ~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/include/endian.h:107:17: error: functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded
  107 | inline uint64_t ToHost(uint64_t value) {
      |        ~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/include/endian.h:91:17: note: previous definition is here
   91 | inline uint16_t ToHost(uint16_t value) {
      |        ~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/include/endian.h:119:17: error: redefinition of 'FromHost'
  119 | inline uint16_t FromHost(uint16_t value) {
      |                 ^
/usr/local/include/endian.h:67:17: note: previous definition is here
   67 | inline uint16_t FromHost(uint16_t value) {
      |                 ^
/usr/local/include/endian.h:127:17: error: functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded
  127 | inline uint32_t FromHost(uint32_t value) {
      |        ~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/include/endian.h:67:17: note: previous definition is here
   67 | inline uint16_t FromHost(uint16_t value) {
      |        ~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/include/endian.h:135:17: error: functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded
  135 | inline uint64_t FromHost(uint64_t value) {
      |        ~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/include/endian.h:67:17: note: previous definition is here
   67 | inline uint16_t FromHost(uint16_t value) {
      |        ~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/include/endian.h:143:17: error: redefinition of 'ToHost'
  143 | inline uint16_t ToHost(uint16_t value) {
      |                 ^
/usr/local/include/endian.h:91:17: note: previous definition is here
   91 | inline uint16_t ToHost(uint16_t value) {
      |                 ^
/usr/local/include/endian.h:151:17: error: functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded
  151 | inline uint32_t ToHost(uint32_t value) {
      |        ~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/include/endian.h:91:17: note: previous definition is here
   91 | inline uint16_t ToHost(uint16_t value) {
      |        ~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/include/endian.h:159:17: error: functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded
  159 | inline uint64_t ToHost(uint64_t value) {
      |        ~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/include/endian.h:91:17: note: previous definition is here
   91 | inline uint16_t ToHost(uint16_t value) {
      |        ~~~~~~~~ ^
In file included from calc.cc:4:
./ast.pb.h:14:10: fatal error: 'google/protobuf/runtime_version.h' file not found
   14 | #include "google/protobuf/runtime_version.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
11 errors generated.
In file included from ast.pb.cc:6:
In file included from ./ast.pb.h:10:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/c++/11/string:55:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.h:6608:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/c++/11/ext/string_conversions.h:41:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/c++/11/cstdlib:75:
In file included from /usr/include/stdlib.h:395:
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:176:
/usr/local/include/endian.h:75:17: error: functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded
   75 | inline uint32_t FromHost(uint32_t value) {
      |        ~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/include/endian.h:67:17: note: previous definition is here
   67 | inline uint16_t FromHost(uint16_t value) {
      |        ~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/include/endian.h:83:17: error: functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded
   83 | inline uint64_t FromHost(uint64_t value) {
      |        ~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/include/endian.h:67:17: note: previous definition is here
   67 | inline uint16_t FromHost(uint16_t value) {
      |        ~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/include/endian.h:99:17: error: functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded
   99 | inline uint32_t ToHost(uint32_t value) {
      |        ~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/include/endian.h:91:17: note: previous definition is here
   91 | inline uint16_t ToHost(uint16_t value) {
      |        ~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/include/endian.h:107:17: error: functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded
  107 | inline uint64_t ToHost(uint64_t value) {
      |        ~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/include/endian.h:91:17: note: previous definition is here
   91 | inline uint16_t ToHost(uint16_t value) {
      |        ~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/include/endian.h:119:17: error: redefinition of 'FromHost'
  119 | inline uint16_t FromHost(uint16_t value) {
      |                 ^
/usr/local/include/endian.h:67:17: note: previous definition is here
   67 | inline uint16_t FromHost(uint16_t value) {
      |                 ^
/usr/local/include/endian.h:127:17: error: functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded
  127 | inline uint32_t FromHost(uint32_t value) {
      |        ~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/include/endian.h:67:17: note: previous definition is here
   67 | inline uint16_t FromHost(uint16_t value) {
      |        ~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/include/endian.h:135:17: error: functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded
  135 | inline uint64_t FromHost(uint64_t value) {
      |        ~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/include/endian.h:67:17: note: previous definition is here
   67 | inline uint16_t FromHost(uint16_t value) {
      |        ~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/include/endian.h:143:17: error: redefinition of 'ToHost'
  143 | inline uint16_t ToHost(uint16_t value) {
      |                 ^
/usr/local/include/endian.h:91:17: note: previous definition is here
   91 | inline uint16_t ToHost(uint16_t value) {
      |                 ^
/usr/local/include/endian.h:151:17: error: functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded
  151 | inline uint32_t ToHost(uint32_t value) {
      |        ~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/include/endian.h:91:17: note: previous definition is here
   91 | inline uint16_t ToHost(uint16_t value) {
      |        ~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/include/endian.h:159:17: error: functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded
  159 | inline uint64_t ToHost(uint64_t value) {
      |        ~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/include/endian.h:91:17: note: previous definition is here
   91 | inline uint16_t ToHost(uint16_t value) {
      |        ~~~~~~~~ ^
In file included from ast.pb.cc:6:
./ast.pb.h:14:10: fatal error: 'google/protobuf/runtime_version.h' file not found
   14 | #include "google/protobuf/runtime_version.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
11 errors generated.

the 2 errors which was present before I copied the header files where:
In file included from ast.pb.cc:6:
./ast.pb.h:14:10: fatal error: 'google/protobuf/runtime_version.h' file not found
   14 | #include "google/protobuf/runtime_version.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

In file included from calc.cc:4:
./ast.pb.h:14:10: fatal error: 'google/protobuf/runtime_version.h' file not found
   14 | #include "google/protobuf/runtime_version.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

So I think I messed up a system header file. How to correct this? My .proto file is ast.proto, the file I'm trying to fuzz using libprotobuf-mutator and libfuzzer is calc.cc. ast.pb.h is the file that was generated after compilation of ast.proto using protoc.
I tried to undo the copy using the command:
cd /usr/local/include/
sudo rm -f src/google/protobuf/*.h
but it didn't work. There were still 11 errors. Please help me resolve this error. Did I corrupt my system header files?

I ran 'sudo mv /usr/local/include/endian.h /usr/local/include/endian_backup.h' and the 11 errors went back to 2 errors. But will this cause any future problems? I'm not sure how the header files work, but I do have a endian.h in /usr/include.
